# MediaElement control doesnot display video only plays the audio of the video in the Grid App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

i'm using MediaElement Control inside the flipview of the itemsdetail page of the GridApp of windows 8 store app and i'm facing a peculiar type of problem using it. The MediaElement does not displays the video there's only a black screen on the intended video output but it plays the audio of the video just fine.

Now the peculiar part of my problem is that in the grid app there are collections of items in a group (i know every one might know this, just for the sake of getting myself clear) , the first item of every group plays the video just fine i mean it displays the video and the audio just fine, but the rest of the items of the group just does not displays the video just plays the audio of the video. Does any one know why is this happening ?

here is the XAML code :

```
 <FlipView
x:Name="flipView"
AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
TabIndex="1"
Grid.RowSpan="2"
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">

<FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,137,0,0"/>
    </Style>
</FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>

<FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid Margin="120,0,20,20">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="400" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="360" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0">
                        <MediaElement x:Name="VideoSource" AutomationProperties.Name="VideoSource" Source="/Assets/Big_Buck_Bunny.mp4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="250" Width="350" AutoPlay="False" IsLooping="True" />
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="65" Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Button x:Name="playButton" Margin="0,0" Click="playButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource PlayAppBarButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Button x:Name="pauseButton" Margin="0,0" Click="pauseButton_Click" Style="{StaticResource PauseAppBarButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</FlipView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the code behind :

```
    private void playButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement media = FindControl<MediaElement>(this, "VideoSource") as MediaElement;
        media.Play();
    }

    private void pauseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement media = FindControl<MediaElement>(this, "VideoSource") as MediaElement;
        media.Pause();
    }

    private void stopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement media = FindControl<MediaElement>(this, "VideoSource") as MediaElement;
        media.Stop();
    }

    private DependencyObject FindControl<T>(DependencyObject controlType, string ctrlName)
    {
        int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(controlType);
        for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(controlType, i);
            FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
            // Not a framework element or is null
            if (fe == null) return null;

            if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
            {
                // Found the control so return
                return child;
            }
            else
            {
                // Not found it - search children
                DependencyObject nextLevel = FindControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
                if (nextLevel != null)
                    return nextLevel;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

i hope i made myself clear on the problem.

Comment: Does the video play in another app?  Try http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Classic-Video-Player-de838b19.

Comment: @Matt Harrington i'm not sure what you are asking, if you are asking that does mediaelement supports that format of video then yes it does play that video format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you are trying will work. To help, though, I wrote up a small prototype.

Use this code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // pause
        var _Media = GetMediaElement(sender as Button);
        _Media.Pause();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // play
        var _Media = GetMediaElement(sender as Button);
        _Media.Play();
    }

    MediaElement GetMediaElement(Button button)
    {
        var _Parent = button.Parent as Grid;
        var _GrandParent = _Parent.Parent as Grid;
        return _GrandParent.Children.First() as MediaElement;
    }

    private void FlipView_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var _FlipView = sender as FlipView;
        foreach (var item in _FlipView.Items)
        {
            var _Container = _FlipView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            var _Children = AllChildren(_Container);
            foreach (var media in _Children)
                media.Pause();
        }
    }

    public List<MediaElement> AllChildren(DependencyObject parent)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            return (new MediaElement[] { }).ToList();
        var _List = new List<MediaElement> { };
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            var _Child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (_Child is MediaElement)
                _List.Add(_Child as MediaElement);
            _List.AddRange(AllChildren(_Child));
        }
        return _List;
    }
}
```

And use this XAML:

```
<FlipView SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged_1">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <MediaElement Source="{Binding}" AutoPlay="False" />
                <Grid Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black">
                    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Pause</Button>
                    <Button Click="Button_Click_2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Play</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>ms-appx:/Assets/BestSingingVideoEver.wmv</x:String>
    <x:String>ms-appx:/Assets/BestSingingVideoEver.wmv</x:String>
    <x:String>ms-appx:/Assets/BestSingingVideoEver.wmv</x:String>
    <x:String>ms-appx:/Assets/BestSingingVideoEver.wmv</x:String>
</FlipView>
```

Be sure and update the path with your own video. Of course you can databind the list, too. My code is just a prototype to prove that what you are wanting to do is possible. Good luck!

I also think I might have resolved a bug or two you had in your code. Especially the part where you hunt for child controls in the list. Here's my reference: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

Comment: Jerry thanks for the reply i'm working on the prototype you gave, will let you know if anything comes up.

At the same time i was thinking that all the other elements in that page receive their data from the databinding, is this possible that i have not bound the source path of the media element that i am facing my problem ?

Comment: Thanks for the help your prototype code the work done and you were right about the bug about my code the problem i think was the way i searched for the mediaelement control, anyways thanks a lot for the help